# Proof $D_2^{-1}D_1$ is a unimodular matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, unimodular-matrices

Consider $G=N_1D_1^{-1}=N_2D_2^{-1}$ and the both descriptions of are composed of coprime matrix, prove that $D_2^{-1}D_1$ is a unimodular matrix.

The matrices $D_i$ and $N_i$ are polinomial.

My attempt:
$N_1D_1^{-1}=N_2D_2^{-1}$ then $N_1=N_2D_2^{-1}D_1$

Using Bezout identity and GCD:

$U_{11}D_1 + U_{12}N_1= R$

$U_{11}D_2D_2^{-1}D_1 + U_{12}N_1= R$

$U_{11}D_2D_2^{-1}D_1 + U_{12}N_2D_2^{-1}D_1= R$

Since R is unimodular, then $U_{11}D_2D_2^{-1}D_1 + U_{12}N_2D_2^{-1}D_1$ is unimodular.
$R^{-1}(U_{11}D_2D_2^{-1}D_1 + U_{12}N_2D_2^{-1}D_1)=I$

$R^{-1}(U_{11}D_2 + U_{12}N_2)=(D_2^{-1}D_1)^{-1}$

$(D_2^{-1}D_1)R^{-1}(U_{11}D_2 + U_{12}N_2)=I$

$U_{11}D_2 + U_{12}N_2=(D_2^{-1}D_1R^{-1})^{-1}$

The LHS is polynomial then the RHS is unimodular, and R is unimodular then $D_2^{-1}D_1$ is unimodular.

Is this proof complete?
Thank you in advanced.

Comment: If $D$ is unimodular then so is $D^{-1}$. If $A,B$ are unimodular then so is $AB$.

Comment: But $D_i$ is not unimodular, it is only coprime to $N_i$

Comment: What ring are you working with?

Comment: It was never mentioned in my class (Where I'm learning the subject). I don't know the ring.